# Find sum of consecutive triangular number recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, recursion, triangular-numbers

In Computer Science, I was asked to write a program that finds the sum of (1 to n)th triangular number, where n is a positive integer.

- If n=1, result is 1
- If n=2, result is (1) + (1 + 2)

By testing values from 1 to 8, I found that T(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + T(n-2) when n > 2.
T(n) is simply n<sup>2</sup> when n=1 or 2.

But how does that work?

EDIT: I am sorry if I haven't clarified yet, but RECURSION is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have it, the triangular numbers are given by:

$$\triangle n=1+2+3+\dots+n$$

and the sum of triangular numbers:

$$T(n)=\triangle1+\triangle2+\triangle3+\dots+\triangle n$$

To verify your recurrence, we can consider differences by rearranging it as $T(n)-T(n-2)=n^2$ and substitute it in to get:

\begin{align}T(n)-T(n-2)&=\overbrace{\triangle1+\triangle2+\dots+\triangle(n-2)+\triangle(n-1)+\triangle n}^{T(n)}\\&-(\underbrace{\triangle1+\triangle2+\dots+\triangle(n-2)}_{T(n-2)})\\&=\triangle(n-1)+\triangle n\\&\stackrel?=n^2\end{align}

So we need to verify if we have:

$$\triangle(n-1)+\triangle n=n^2$$

This can be done once again by considering differences since it is clear that it holds for $n=1$, leaving us with:

$$\underbrace{\triangle(n-1)+\triangle n}_{n^2}-\underbrace{\triangle(n-2)-\triangle(n-1)}_{(n-1)^2}=n^2-(n-1)^2$$

These reduce down to:

\begin{align}\triangle n-\triangle(n-2)&=\overbrace{1+2+\dots+(n-2)+(n-1)+n}^{\triangle n}\\&-(\underbrace{1+2+\dots+(n-2)}_{\triangle(n-2)})\\&=(n-1)+n\\&=2n-1\\&=n^2-n^2+2n-1\\&=n^2-(n-1)^2\end{align}

which inductively verifies $\triangle(n-1)+\triangle n=n^2$, and hence $T(n)=T(n-2)+n^2$.

---

Note: It is likely the task wanted you to find a direct recurrence. There's a lot of work here to verify the recurrence, which is probably not expected. Often times you should simply try working it by hand. Then you may've realized that it's straightforward to compute it iteratively as follows:

```
function sum_of_triangles(n)
  sum = 0
  triangle = 0
  for k in 1..n
    triangle += k
    sum += triangle
  end
  return sum
```

Writing this "purely" with recursively defined functions is fairly messy though if one does not have the formula for $\triangle n$ at hand. If one did, then this can be worked out as

```
function sum_of_triangles(n)
  if n == 0
    return 0
  else
    return sum_of_triangles(n-1) + triangle(n) // triangle(n) = n*(n+1)/2
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! The task requires recursion to be used. However, I wrote a function like [this](https://github.com/TCLRainbow/SchoolBasic/blob/956c5f43aa544a502f2522ac52865ab39522648a/SchoolBasic/Recursion/Exercise.vb#L19)

Comment: That should work, but seeing as you already have the `SumTo` function for the triangular numbers, I would imagine it was expected of you to use the code similar to what I have at the end of my answer.

Comment: In fact, the model answer has the same approach as yours. `SumTo` is another task, and I don't know if I am supposed to use it in this task. I think my function should require less computation though.

Comment: The matter of which has more or less computation is largely irrelevant to the task. If they had wanted you to compute it efficiently, they would've had it solved as in Math1000's answer, but that is not the point of the exercise.

Comment: What I meant was comparing the recursive functions. Anyways as you've said this is out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

If $t(n)$ is the $n$-th triangular number and $T(n)$ is the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers, $T(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n t(k)$, then
$$
T(n) - T(n-2) = t(n)+t(n-1) = \frac12 n(n+1) + \frac12(n-1)(n) = \frac12 n(n+1+n-1) = n^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, this does explain it in a simple way using only maths!

Answer (score 0):

This is called Pascal's Triangle. The triangular numbers are the third diagonal (first is all ones). The cumulative sums are in the fourth diagonal.

Also see the answer by Yves at [Triangular numbers and pascal's trangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826172/triangular-numbers-and-pascals-trangle)

[image]